# How to programmatically turn on Wifi hotspot on Android api level 23?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, hotspot

The program needs to switch on a hotspot with custom SSID and password, but I can't find any API to do so on Marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following standalone class :

```
import android.content.*;
import android.net.wifi.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class ApManager {

    //check whether wifi hotspot on or off
    public static boolean isApOn(Context context) {
        WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        try {
            Method method = wifimanager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("isWifiApEnabled");
            method.setAccessible(true);
            return (Boolean) method.invoke(wifimanager);
        }
        catch (Throwable ignored) {}
        return false;
    }

    // toggle wifi hotspot on or off
    public static boolean configApState(Context context) {
        WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiConfiguration wificonfiguration = null;
        try {
            // if WiFi is on, turn it off
            if(isApOn(context)) {
                wifimanager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            }
            Method method = wifimanager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
            method.invoke(wifimanager, wificonfiguration, !isApOn(context));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now once you have created the class the following permissions are to be added to your Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

After doing the above, the following code toggles the Hotspot:

`ApManager.configApState(MainActivity.this);`

You need to pass the accurate context in place of `MainActivity.this`.

I used this class a long ago and don't exactly remember the source I took it from.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Nothing happens. The wifi just switches off, thats all.

Comment: Which android version are you currently on? I am on Android 6.0.1, MIUI8.